# Python Matplotlib lines in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

Is there a way to influence which points are connected in a scatter plot?

I want a scatter plot where the points which are close together are connected. When I plot with the `plot(x,y)` command, the line between the points depends on the order of the lists which is not what I want.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you want to connect dots *close* together? Or are they enclosed by something?

Comment: Can you give some sample data and an example output (that is not what you want to see)?

Comment: what do you mean the points in a scatter plot are 'connected'? they should not be.....Can you show us some code and an image?

Comment: Sounds more like you want [`scipy.spatial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/spatial.html).  Look at the plotting helpers.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make it clearer what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: Specifically, the comment you left on a now-deleted answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am taking a hint from the wording of your questions that you have two sets of points x,y that are unordered. When you plot them (not in a scatter plot as @tcaswell points out; this would not connect the dots!), the line connecting the points will therefore follow the order of the points.

If this is the issue you want to solve, it can be done like so:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)

# Plot non-ordered points
ax1.plot(x, y, marker="o", markerfacecolor="r")

# Order points by their x-value
indexs_to_order_by = x.argsort()
x_ordered = x[indexs_to_order_by]
y_ordered = y[indexs_to_order_by]

ax2.plot(x_ordered, y_ordered, marker="o", markerfacecolor="r")
```

The important point is, if the data you are working with are numpy arrays (if they are lists just call `np.array(list)`) then `argsort` returns the indices of the sorted array. Using these indices means we can pairwise sort the two lists and plot in the correct order as shown on the right:

[image: Non-sorted and sorted plots]

If I have misinterpreted your questions then I apologise. In that case, please leave a comment and I will try to remove my answer.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry i seemed to be unclear in my question. I have to sets of points x, y, which i want to plot in a scatter. But I do not want to plot them in x ascending order, but I want to have the points with the smallest distance between them connected. (Like excel does, when you add lines to a scatter plot)

Comment: The way you word this suggests only one set of points will be connected, is this correct or do you mean "each point is connected to it's nearest neighbour", that is do you envision a single line being drawn or many?

Comment: i always want connect the nearest neighbours, but in a way that each node as maximum of degree two, so i want to have on line which connects all points, not a tree/ star like structure.

Comment: I think you need to define your connections before you try to plot it. If you connect *only* the nearest neighbours, then you will separate the list of points into pairs of points, in this case each point will have a maximum degree of 1. This is because each point can only have 1 nearest neighbour by definition, their is no other way. So you need to add a second condition on how you then connect these pair of points up..

Comment: Coming a bit late, but though this may not have answered the original question, it did answer mine - would it make sense to re-ask the question that you actually answered here?

Comment: @kevbonham If you think it is valuable to others feel free to re-ask and answer the question yourself. I should really have deleted this as I said I would!